Github for Visual Studio 2022

I couldn't log in to Github from Visual Studio 2022 to upload the code to Github. I researched, but couldn't find a solution. I also took down Visual Studio to save it but it didn't work, so I came here to ask everyone for help.
Please help me fix the Github login error in Visual Studio 2022

When you "copy error information", does it say more than "failed"? If so, please add (as plain text) to your question

Can you successfully login via a web browser?

Try below methods to solve your issue.

Clear Cached Credentials.


Go to Windows Credentials Manager (search "Credential Manager" in the
Windows search bar).
Under Windows Credentials, look for any entries related to
github.com or Visual Studio, then remove them.
Restart Visual Studio and try logging in again.


Reconfigure GitHub Account in Visual Studio.


Open Visual Studio 2022 and go to File > Account Settings > All
Accounts.
If GitHub appears, try removing and re-adding the account.
Click Add an account, select GitHub, and follow the prompts to log in.

